# Check if date expression ("d-m" without leading zeros) is today

Tags: php, date

I want to compare current date's day and month with subscription date's day and month only.
For example:

```
current date(d-m) = 3-6
```

And I want compare it with any other **d-m**
How should I do it in PHP
In my project condition is like birth date in which we don't compare year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick in this is to let the month come first. This way PHP can compare the numbers by highest value. Take a look at the following example:

```
$aDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', '05-20');
$bDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', '06-29');

if ($aDate->format('md') > $bDate->format('md')) {
    echo "'aDate' is bigger than 'bDate'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use like

```
$current_date = date("d-m");
$subscription = "03-06-2016";
$subscription_date  = date("d-m", strtotime($subscription));
if($current_date ==$subscription_date)
{
    echo "date is equal";
}else
{
    echo "date is not equal";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check if the `j-n` date is the same as the current date, then you don't need to make more than one function call.  Because you are not comparing greater than or less than, the format of your input is unimportant.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rtZQ8))

```
$subscription = '29-11';
var_export(date("j-n") === $subscription);
// at the moment, the result is true
```

- `j` is today's day of the month without any leading zeros and
- `n` is today's month without any leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT() function to extract part of date:

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(subscription_date, '%d-%m') = "05-05";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime() PHP objects.

Considering you have an array with user info from mysql query result: (`$userData['suscriptionDate']`)

```
$today = new DateTime();

$userSuscription = new DateTime($userData['suscriptionDate']);

if ( $today->format('d') == $userSuscription->format('d') && $today->format('m') == $userSuscription->format('m')) {

    echo 'Congratulations!!';
}
```

Comment: Your if statement is incorrect. The day can be bigger but if it is next month, the one date should still be higher.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
$sdate = $row['subscription_date'];
$date1 = date("m-d");
$date2 = date("m-d",strtotime($sdate)) ;
if ($date1 == $date2) {

}
```

Comment: Is double "m" and double "d" the correct way, I wonder?

Comment: This code-only answer does not work with the OP's `3-6`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, more elegant way to compare, especially when you have a full date with time is `diff` function of `Datetime` class:

```
$d1 = new Datetime();
$d2 = new Datetime('+3 months +2 days +3 hours');

$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
var_dump($diff->d); // 2
var_dump($diff->m); // 2
// or have a comparison as a string
var_dump($diff->format('Difference is in %R%a days'));
// output: Difference is in 63 days
```

Enjoy! [Link to doc](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php)